# Cordova - How to display push notification without server

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3

I have an app that displays a map and tracks your location. There are several pins on the map. I want to push a notification whenever the users location is close to a pin. I have everything set up (background location is working) except for the push notification itself.

Is it possible to push a notification without having the need to set up a server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can generate Local Notification using cordova plugin.
This notification will be shown in system tray in the same device.

more information refer:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

This plugin is supported in iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8 platforms.